# How to stop every time cells changing to value after coping data to another sheet in EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to write perfectly working code but am faced with this issue. I want to transfer the data as values to another sheet. To fill out the data I use a form with formulas inside cells.

Then every time I click to transfer the data to another sheet it replaces the source data with its values in both sheets, but for me need that forms cells in the `sheet1` stay unchanged. I use a form  with formula to put data in the `sheet1` from different sources, so it should work every time then I use it (now, after each click I have to recover formulas in the `sheet1`).

Here is the code:

```
Sub Button4_Click()
    Dim x As Long
    Dim erow as Long

'Calculate starting rows
x = 15
With Worksheets("Sheet2")
    erow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Do While .Cells(x, 1) <> ""
        'Current code replaces the source data with its values'
        .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value

        'The next line copies values to Sheet2
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & erow & ":Y" & erow).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value

        'increment row counters
        x = x + 1
        erow = erow + 1
    Loop
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Assigning `.Value` is essentially the same thing as "Paste Values".  What do you expect the result to be when there's an existing formula in the target cell?

Answer (score 0):

You can't write to a cell's `.Formula` and then add unrelated data to the same cell's `.Value` - writing to `.Value` deletes the formula.
So the following code line:

```
.Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value = .Range("A" & x & ":Y" & x).Value
```

is unnecessary (and damaging).